# Paragraph text from model object coming in same line

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which is used to show details from database. My index view for an entity having only one property i.e. text is

```
@foreach( var item in model)
{
     <p class="col-md-4">@Item.text</p>
}
```

If the text field is too long, it is shown in a single line and a horizontal scroll bar appears. I want it to flow to next line. Kindly help me figure out the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, just use [`word-break: break-all;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

```css
p {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<p class="col-md-4">LOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUMLOREMISPUM</p>
```

Comment: Oh Thanks man. You saved my day. I spent hours on internet searching for something like this, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck!